# facebook developer alert confusion

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In my facebook developer app's upgrade tool, I'm told to do these

[image]

In my code however, I'm only using these after the user allow access in facebook :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,name&access_token=strToken
```

The setting for "Enforce app restrictions on API calls" is set to "No"

[image]

so my question is, is the alert safe to ignore ? I'm utterly confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert is saying 'if your app has geographic restrictions, these changes in v2.10 will affect you' - it's based on a sample of your app's API calls, and comparing those calls to which calls have upcoming changes

If you don't actually have restrictions in place, you can ignore this alert.

Note that the second screenshot you added isn't showing if you have geographic restrictions enabled, it's showing if you're already enabled the behaviour that the first alert is warning you about.

You can see if you have geographic restrictions enabled in the app settings, Advanced tab, screenshot:
[image: Settings page screenshot showing restrictions]

If you do have restrictions configured, you'll need to either start making your API calls with an `appsecret_proof` parameter, or accept that for some users, your calls will stop working if the user doesn't meet the configured restrictions

Comment: thank you very much. Mine has no such restrictions. Thanks for clearing it up !